# Script stops returning value on adding dataType: 'json'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been stuck on this for days now...the problem is this: I want to get multiple values from a PHP file through jQuery Ajax Json. but as soon as i add the `dataType: 'json',` to it, that's the end of things. I am using the given code:

---

PHP - check.php

```
$oid=1;
$f=10;
echo json_encode(array("oid" => $oid, "cid" => $f));
```

PS: THE ABOVE CODE IS INSIDE A LOOP THAT RETURNS MANY oid's AND cid's AT ONE TIME!

I've not included the part above or below the script cause it can compromise the security of my site.. :P but this in a nutshell is what the script does.

and here goes the javascript:

---

jQuery - scripts.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "check.php",
    data: {anu:"bhav"}
}).done(function( result ) {
    if(result!='0'){
        var res=result.oid[0];
        alert(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is `result` when you remove the dataType ?

Comment: Then the `result` is something like this: {"oid":"1","cid":"10"}

Comment: And you're not ouputting anything else, no whitespace before or after the PHP tags etc.

Comment: It does seem strange to check if `result` equals the string `"0"` when you're **always** expecting JSON to be returned? You did of course try to just console.log(result) as well, as `result.oid[0]` doesn't look like it would match anything in that object ?

Comment: yeah...no output before that...and i am using `"0"` as a return value if any error occurs.. :P

Comment: And that would create an error in itself, as it's not JSON, and the $.ajax call would fail to parse it.

Comment: i have re-written the code as this- `$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result)
    {
var res = result.oid[0];
alert(res);
    }
});` is it ok??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code before `echo json_encode(array("oid" => $oid, "cid" => $f));`

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Change below line

```
var res = result.oid[0];
```

As below and try:

```
var res = result.oid;
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is inside a loop, you need to build an array with all your arrays in it.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    $oid=1;
    $f=10;
    $results[] = array("oid" => $oid, "cid" => $f));
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> PS: THE ABOVE CODE IS INSIDE A LOOP THAT RETURNS MANY oid's AND cid's AT ONE TIME!

That one line of information is almost certain to be the ultimate cause of your problem.

Echoing multiple blocks of JSON one after the other **does not** result in one large block of valid JSON.

It results in a string that **may look like JSON but is not valid**, and will not produce any data if you pass it through a JSON parser.

Your PHP program should print one, and only one JSON block, generated by a single call to `json_encode()`.

You can do this by copying the data into an array inside your loop, rather than echoing it there, and then doing your json_encode()` call on that big array, rather than the individual  blocks of data.

Hope that helps explain things.